# Check the properties of given polynomial of order $7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Consider $$f(x)=x^{7}-105x+12$$ Then which of the following is\are correct?
>
> - $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$
> - There exists an integer $m$ such that $f(m)= 105$
> - There exists an integer $m$ such that $f(m)=2$
> - $f(m)$ is not a prime for any integer $m$

The function is continuous and attain every value on real plane but, the main problem here is about "$m$" which is integer.I only know how to check irreducibility of given polynomial but here it is asking about reducibility,one think i know about reducibility is if polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb Z$ then it is reducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Eisenstein with $p=3$ the first is not true.

The second is not true because the equation $x^7-105x-93=0$ has no integer roots. We need to check only $\{\pm1,\pm3\pm31\pm93\}$

By the same way we can get that the third is wrong.

The fourth is true because $f(m)$ is an even number and the third is wrong.

Comment: thnx ,i was confused in how will i solve 93^7, now i can see i don't need to calculate it ,will end up more then zero.

Comment: @gaurav saini $93^7$ is too big. See please better. It's just obvious that it's not a root.

Comment: How did we conclude that $x^7-105x-93$ has no integer roots? I can not see it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: @StammeringMathematician if $m$ is an integer root of $x^7-105x-93$ so $x^7-105x-93=(x-m)(x^6+ax^5+...+bx+c)$, where $a$, $b$,   , $c$ are integers. Thus, $93=mc$ and $m$ divides $93$. Id est, it's enough to check $m\in\{\pm1,\pm3\pm31,\pm93\}$, which gives that it's impossible. Also, we can see it by Eisenstein again.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The question says $x^7-105x-12$, while you have solve the problem for $x^7-105x-93$ Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician It was the answer on the second question. See please better the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see it now.@MichaelRozenberg